# Event Categories in GA4 (Google Analytics)

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

After migrating to [Google Analytics GA4](https://analytics.google.com), I noticed that I can't seem to find a way to search the event categories as I did in Universal Analytics.

In code I pass an event like this:

```
gtag('event', 'orders_puppy', { event_category: 'sales_group'});
```

In the GA4 UI, how can I see all the **event_categories** to drill down to the **orders_puppy** event?

Comment: There are no event categories in GA4. You have to register custom dimensions (called event properties) in GA4.

Comment: This should be an answer as it is correct.   What stinks is I see no way of querying out the properties

Answer (score 0):

So as stated in one of the comments the event_category is no longer a built in Dimension.   You can set up custom dimensions to continue to collect and report off of this just as before.   Here is a video that demonstrates how to set that up.

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10075209?sjid=11766517785558019197-NA

It is a bit annoying that it won't process the dimensions until you configure the custom dimension so any that you sent in while migrating is lost.